# Get string from Firebase Timestamp with format

Tags: javascript, firebase, date, google-cloud-firestore

I'm fetching a `Timestamp` object from `Firebase/Firestore`. I want to present the date in a `dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm` format.

I've tried to convert it to JS date and use `toString()`, but I can't figure out how can I set the format:

```
const dateString = doc.data()["date"].toDate().toString();
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firestore library doesn't have any facilities to format a timestamp.  However, since you're able to convert it to a JavaScript Date object using `toDate()`, you can then use libraries such as [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) to format the date in very flexible ways.  If you can't use that, you can format it yourself using [Date's own instance methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Instance_methods) to get the calendar components out of it.